# well i was just learner and tried to link different components together it's not working out

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i fix these error's

[image: 1]

I tried every way possible to fix these error's!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Make sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and when possible, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue so the community can better understand the problem and provide you with better answers. Also, [avoid uploading images of code/errors/data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13927534) in your question.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are not using latest version of react-router-dom.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).